# URL Routes In IIS7 MVC 5 (Single Paged Application)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

After publishing a MVC5 web application of mine to my IIS server (Individual User Accounts), it would seem that the URL is accessed incorrectly.

During debug, it would be e.g `http://localhost:1234/api/Account/UserInfo?=XXXXX`
The debug works just fine. The only issue kicks in after I've published it via my IIS7 server.

After publishing and using Google Chrome's console, it would appear that the page is requesting for a resource at `mydomainname.com/api/Account/UserInfo?=XXXX` instead of `mydomainname.com/WEBAPPLICATIONNAME/api/Account/UserInfo?=XXXX`.

My best guess is to modify the URLs in `/Scripts/app/app.datamodel.js` but it would just cause more parsing problems.

I've searched around and can't seem to find any related problems. I hope someone here will be able to lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are using relative path like "/api/Account/UserInfo". Instead i'll recommend you to use `@Url.Content("/api/Account/UserInfo")`. This will solve your problem

**Explanation**

In local system when we run application in WebDev server it never have sub folder (like WEBAPPLICATIONNAME) therefore you relative path work correctly. but when you host your application in IIS under Default website in another new website /Virtual folder (like 'WEBAPPLICATIONNAME') then "/api/Account/UserInfo" fall back to Default Website because for '/' in starting. `@Url.Content` or `@Url.Action` make sure to add virtual directory name, hence changing your path to "/WEBAPPLICATIONNAME/api/Account/UserInfo" in IIS.